# Is this piece of code correct? #Leetcode 550

Tags: mysql

I'm working on this problem and I found this piece of code.

```
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT player_id)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT player_id) FROM Activity),2) AS fraction
FROM Activity
WHERE (player_id, event_date) IN
(SELECT player_id, DATE(MIN(event_date)+1)
FROM Activity
GROUP BY player_id)
```

However, I only know the DATE_ADD function in MySQL. Is this usage here correct? Adding a date type variable with a integer and then using the DATE function to convert it.

What's the result of adding a date type variable with a integer? And according to W3Schools, the DATE() function is used to extract the date part from a datetime expression?

The SQL schema is

```
Create table If Not Exists Activity (player_id int, device_id int, event_date date, games_played int)
Truncate table Activity
insert into Activity (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played) values ('1', '2', '2016-03-01', '5')
insert into Activity (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played) values ('1', '2', '2016-03-02', '6')
insert into Activity (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played) values ('2', '3', '2017-06-25', '1')
insert into Activity (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played) values ('3', '1', '2016-03-02', '0')
insert into Activity (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played) values ('3', '4', '2018-07-03', '5')
```

from Leetcode

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE(MIN(event_date)+1)
```

Since `event_date` is a DATE datatype, do this  instead:

```
MIN(event_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(It seems strange to want the day *after* the oldest date; is that really what is called for?)